# How to disable the components exist warning?

Tags: inno-setup

So I've made a setup with a lot of components, and I'm updating this setup quite often, so my users has to redownload a new version and always encounter this annoying notification window:
Like, 
 [image]

It's ok as long as it's small, but when I have a very long list of components, and I have it often, then this window is simply too hight, and cannot be moved or even closed if someone has a low screen resolution. There is a huge problem with this.

My question is simple: how to disable this window, or make it not sticking out of the windows desktop area?

Comment: "always encounter this annoying notification window"? It should only appear when the user explicitly unchecks a component where the message is normally appropriate unless you've added explicit handling to remove components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must include the [`disablenouninstallwarning`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_componentssection.htm#disablenouninstallwarning) flag for all your [`[Components]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_componentssection.htm) section entries to disable this warning globally. For example:

```
[Components]
Name: "app"; Description: "App"; Types: full; Flags: disablenouninstallwarning
Name: "help"; Description: "Help"; Types: full; Flags: disablenouninstallwarning
```

Comment: P.S. I know it's bothering to include it to every component entry, but there's currently no global setting for this... FYI, [`it's happening here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Wizard.pas#L2165).

Comment: Maybe it's not a global solution, but still a good one, thank you.